# AngularJS test check p contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, matcher

I am trying to write an end-to-end test which checks if a p tag exists containing some specific text:

```
it('should display search result snippet for a result item', function() {
    input('query').enter('One');
    element('#submitSearchButton').click();
    expect(element('.emails li p').text()).toEqual('This is a search result snippet for email one')
})
```

However I get:

```
expected "This is a search result snippet for email one" but was "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tThis is a search result snippet for email one\n\t\t\t\t\t"
```

How can I check that the page contains the text required?

**Edit:**

Ok, I see this is because I am testing something that is in an HTML template.  This template has formatting to make it easier to read but I got confused because I was looking at the rendered web page in a browser:

```
<p>
     {{email.snippet}}
</p>
```

My question now is how should I go about testing in an angular e2e test that my email snippet is rendered as expected?  Should I re-format the template or should I be going about this in a different way?

Comment: use  regex to test the value instead of direct comparison

Comment: You shouldn't have that static value in your test. Where does the value come from? With the newlines and tabs, I assume it comes from an HTML file, which makes me wonder why you're testing it contains what was manually written to it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why did someone down-vote me for this question?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why your code look like that. In jQuery to check if p contain some text you just need to do:

```
if ($('p:contains("someText")').length > 0) {
    // Your code here
}
```